# Windows batch file : PID of last process?

Tags: windows, browser, batch-file, pid

I am launching a browser from batch file.

```
START "www.google.com"
```

I would like to know the PID of this browser window launched.

There can be many browser windows launched on a single machine. I need to find the PID of the process which was launched by my batch file only. I tried with WINDOWTITLE filter. But its not a good idea as titles may change in future. I am using Windows XP/7

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: How does `START "www.google.com"` open a browser window? According to the doc, START "title" opens a new console window with the title specified.

Comment: I am sorry, it has to be, START "title" "www.google.com"

Comment: Think this post belongs on Super User

Comment: I am after this solution. I want to open a browser, run an iMacros script and then close it down again. I can 'taskkill /im firefox' but obviously this might be dangerous! if the 'start' could return a PID I could use that.

Comment: There is no guarantee that "start" will start a new process. Many Web browsers will simply open a new tab with the page, and if you take out the process you take out all the tabs not just the one you opened.

Answer (score 3):

For what it worth (question is more than 2 years old) this code do the trick, just change variable according to default browser exe

```
set "browser=palemoon.exe"

tasklist /FI "imagename eq %browser%" /NH /FO csv > task-before.txt
start www.google.com
tasklist /FI "imagename eq %browser%" /NH /FO csv > task-after.txt

:: fc /L /LB1  test4-Before.txt test4-After.txt | find /I "%browser%"
for /f "delims=, tokens=2,*" %%A in ('"fc /L /LB1  task-before.txt task-after.txt | find /I "%browser%""') do set pid=%%A

SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
pid=!pid:"=!
ENDLOCAL
echo pid is %pid%
```

Comment: What is `pid=!pid:"=!` supposed to mean? I get "'pid' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea, to get you maybe on the way

there is a command called  Tasklist

there is a switch called filter /FI with lets you decide what filter parameters you want to output, f.e PID. Output this to a   > 1.TXT

start your proces

recheck the watchlist and output to 2.TXT

Then you would have to get creative. COmpare 1 to 2,
maybe remove the processes in 1 from the 2.TXT
The remainig PID is what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

If you have some programming experience, you could create your own console application that accepts command-line parameters and passes them to the Win32 API `CreateProcess()` function. One of its output values is the spawned process ID, which your app could then return.  Then just update your batch file to call your app instead of using `START` directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same thing. Though there must be some way of doing it, but all my Googling suggests not.

Check out [robvanderwoude.com](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/processes.php) to see a list of 3rd party tools and examples. Also check out the full list of Sysinternal's process utilities [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb795533).

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at this for about 2 hours now and I think that there is a way to do this, but it requires some more insight on how windows handles iexplore.exe for PID...

I have a working version of a batch file I wrote that will get you what you want, BUT **only if** its the FIRST AND ONLY Internet Explorer Window open.

For some reason I can't get the PID to change when I open new browsers, but I can get results if there is no window open (obviously because there is no PID)

Anyhow, this is what I have... you should be able to run this on your system and it will tell you that there are no differences and it might actually produce results if your default browser is Firefox or Chrome or something... just need to make the changes to what I'm providing.

```
@echo off
IF EXIST c:\temp\pshell.txt del c:\temp\pshell.txt
IF EXIST C:\temp\PID1.txt del C:\temp\PID1.txt
IF EXIST C:\temp\PID2.txt del C:\temp\PID2.txt
IF EXIST C:\temp\PowerFormat.txt del C:\temp\PowerFormat.txt
powershell.exe Get-Process iexplore>C:\temp\pshell.txt
FOR /F "skip=3 tokens=7 delims= " %%1 IN ( c:\temp\pshell.txt ) DO @echo %%1>> C:\temp\PID1.txt
start "title" "www.google.com"
powershell.exe Get-Process iexplore>C:\temp\pshell.txt
FOR /F "skip=3 tokens=7 delims= " %%2 IN ( c:\temp\pshell.txt ) DO @echo %%2>> C:\temp\PID2.txt

FC /L c:\temp\pid1.txt c:\temp\pid2.txt> C:\temp\FileComparison.txt
FOR /F "tokens=7 delims=" %%3 IN (c:\temp\FileComparison.txt) DO @echo %%3>C:\temp\DiffPID.txt

FINDSTR "FC: no differences encountered" c:\temp\FileComparison.txt
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' del C:\temp\FileComparison.txt & echo.No PID Found
IF NOT '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0'  type c:\temp\FileComparison.txt

pause
exit
```

Let me know if this helps...